# What is the shutdown command in 13.04 to display new unity shutdown dialog?

Tags: unity, launcher, shutdown

I want to create a shutdown icon for the launcher in 13.04. In former versions of Ubuntu I used this desktop file and put it in the launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shut Down
TryExec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown
Icon=system-shutdown
Terminal=false
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Categories=System;
Version=1.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-session
```

What is the shutdown command in 13.04 to display this new unity shutdown dialog?

Here is a screenshot with:

[image]

PS: also this command may be useful to shutdown computer in lircrc file configuration